# why won't VS Code let me use 'name' as an argument in the constructor?

Tags: angular, constructor, parameter-passing, typescript

I'm working on a project and I'm trying to figure out why VS Code keeps telling me "name" is deprecated when I try to use it as a parameter in the consturctor. I've also tried changing "name" to something else, like "pick" and it just tells me it can't find the name. Any ideas what's going on? (BTW this is supposed to be in vanilla TypeScript format)

Here's my TS code:

```
    export class Recipe {
        public name: string;
        public description: string;
        public imagePath: string;
    }
    
    constructor(name: string, desc: string, imagePath: string) {
        this.name = name;
        
    
    }
```

I can't save this without getting some sort of error that says 'name' is deprecated, and I get a big dash through the variable.

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. Constructors may only be inside a class body.

Comment: @CertainPerformance wow, I feel really dumb lol. thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The constructor belongs in the class in order to work like you want it.
Having the constructor outside of the class, will result in `this` having another value and not the instance of the class.

The deprecation warning comes from a typing inside the `lib.dom.d.ts`.
Moving the constructor inside the class will fix your issue.